# Unique identifier for Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have a pub/subscribe queue in Spring Integration. Once a message is put on the queue I can see a new message ID is generated and different message ID for each of the subscribers. I want to use the initial unique message ID as an unique identifier while it flows through various microservices subscribers. Can I get the original message ID from each of the subscribers?

Also if I had multiple spring integration instances writing the messages into a single kafka queue, would message ID be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Kafka deserves its own SO question. Re. *the same id for all the subflows*: how about a `applySequence = true` for the `PublishSubscribeChannel` and each message copy will be send with the `Sequence Details` headers where the `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID` is exactly copy of the original message?

The problem with Messaging that each new message should be really a new unique object. This way each message is a stand along entity and it doesn't effect all others and even may not know about their existence. The *stateless* is one of the consistency goals of Messaging per se.

Therefore if you would like to carry some identificator to all the messages, you should consider to use some other header, not an `id`. For this purpose the Framework already provides for your conventional mechanism called *correlation* and *sequence details*: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel

Comment: Thanks Artem. Yes, I think using another header is the better way. I took a look at the link but I'm not sure how that works, should I be autogenerating the identificator? If you could point me to any examples that would be great.

Comment: Well, the channel with that option will do the trick for you and you should look for the `correlationId` header downstreams